# Why I get Attribute Error when slicing through object type rows in a dataframe with .str accessor?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains dates and mobile numbers. I converted the mobile numbers to "object" dtype so I could slice through them. But I get attribute error. I checked the dtype of my mobile numbers to be object and it seems everything is ok. I also used errors= "ignore" argument when I open my csv file but nothing changed.

This is the first two rows of my dataframe:

| User Mobile New Etl | Registered Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2196669066 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2196669066 | 2021-02-01 |

My columns names are: "User Mobile New Etl" and "Registered Date".

I used these line of codes:

```
users = pd.read_csv("hotel_users.csv")
users = users.sort_values(by="User Mobile New Etl")
users.iloc[:,0] = users["User Mobile New Etl"].astype('object').str[:3]
```

And it returns this error:
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: Why not use ```.astype(str)``` ?

Comment: Looks like your column is int type, not string.